# How to update this script to generate HLS video with different resolution streams?

Tags: ffmpeg, hls

I have the following FFmpeg script:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i video.vtt \
 -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map 1 \
 -s:v:0 1080x1920 -c:v:0 h264 -b:v:0 500K \
 -c:a:0 copy -c:a:1 copy -c:a:2 copy -c:s webvtt \
 -f hls -hls_playlist_type vod -var_stream_map "v:0,a:0,s:0" \
 -master_pl_name video.m3u8 -hls_time 6 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_allow_cache 1 -start_number 1 \
 -hls_segment_filename "output/hls/%v/seg-%d.ts" output/hls/%v/index.m3u8
```

Currently it only produces one 1080x1920 stream, how do I produce more lower resolution ones so it can adjust based on client bandwidth?

Also, I've noticed that it doesn't add the reference to the VTT file to the master HLS playlist; I had to add this manually but is there a way to make FFmpeg do it for me?

```
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",NAME="English",DEFAULT=YES,AUTOSELECT=YES,FORCED=NO,LANGUAGE="en",CHARACTERISTICS="public.accessibility.transcribes-spoken-dialog",URI="0/index_vtt.m3u8"
```

I've tried this, but I get an argument error:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i video.vtt \
 -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map 1 \
 -s:v:0 1080x1920 -c:v:0 h264 -b:v:0 500K \
 -s:v:1 720x1280 -c:v:1 h264 -b:v:1 300K \
 -s:v:2 480x854 -c:v:2 h264 -b:v:2 150K \
 -c:a:0 copy -c:a:1 copy -c:a:2 copy -c:s webvtt \
 -f hls -hls_playlist_type vod -var_stream_map "v:0,a:0,s:0 v:1,a:1 s:1 v:2,a:2 s:2" \
 -master_pl_name video.m3u8 -hls_time 6 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_allow_cache 1 -start_number 1 \
 -hls_segment_filename "output/hls/%v/seg-%d.ts" output/hls/%v/index.m3u8
```

Comment: Create additional maps for the other resolutions that you want.

Comment: @TheSomberi Thank you! Are you able to give me an example on how to do that? I'm still a beginner with ffmpeg so I'm not sure about the syntax.

Comment: You must add `-map` options for each resolution, as described in https://ottverse.com/hls-packaging-using-ffmpeg-live-vod/